# Find functions from partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ and $y$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
>   And suppose that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0, \quad\quad f(1,2)=g(1,2)=5,\quad\quad f(0,0)=4$$
>   Find $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$

I was able to find two planes:
$$z=\frac12x +\frac9{2}\\ z=\frac12y+4$$
However, I am wondering if other solutions, that are not planes, exist. I just want to know they exist, not what they are.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only solutions of the given problem are the ones that you have provided.

Note that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =0$ implies that $f$ is a function of $y$ only. That is, $f(x,y) = h(y)$. Similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ implies $g(x,y)=r(x)$.

Now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ implies $h'(y)=r'(x)$. Since the left-hand side is a function of $y$, whereas the right-hand side is a function of $x$, $$h'(y)=r'(x)=k,$$
where $k$ is a constant. Consequently, $$f(x,y)=h(y)=ky+c_1,$$ and $$g(x,y)=r(x)=kx+c_2.$$

Now $f(0,0)=4 \implies c_1=4$, and $f(1,2)=5 \implies k=1/2$. As such, $$f(x,y)=\frac{y}{2}+4.$$
Lastly, $g(1,2)=5 \implies c_2 = 5 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{9}{2}$. Therefore,
$$g(x,y) = \frac{x+9}{2}.$$

Comment: Yeah I made a typing mistake I’ll fix it. Yeah that was my same procedure.